# another Setup.py error: option -f not recognized

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a setup file in the following jupyernotebook structure:

Reconstruction/
         **init**.py
         models/
            custom_loader
            **init**.py
         utils
            **init**.py
            data_prep
         setup.py

But I keep getting this error message.  Does anyone know any fixes?

```
from distutils.core import setup  

setup(
    name='Reconstruction1',
    version='1.0', 
    py_modules=['Reconstruction'],
)



An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] 
[cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: ipykernel_launcher.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: ipykernel_launcher.py --help-commands
   or: ipykernel_launcher.py cmd --help

error: option -f not recognized
/Users/bhaveshgopal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3275: UserWarning: To exit: use 
'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

I'm following this:
[Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder/50194143#50194143)

The 'Solution without sys.path hacks' part of that ^ link